# java jbutton text does not fit on different environments

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, centos, jbutton

I have a jbutton in a Jpanel which has FlowLayout with trailing alignment.
This code actually works in ubuntu environment but when i run it in the centos enviornment,
text does not fit on the button.

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
myButton = new JButton("My Text");
buttonPanel.add(myButton);
```

Then I add the following lines:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
myButton = new JButton("My Text");
int width=myButton.getFontMetrics(exportButton.getFont()).stringWidth(myButton.getText());
int height=myButton.getFontMetrics(myButton.getFont()).getHeight()+10;
myButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width+30, height));
buttonPanel.add(myButton);
```

This additional lines helped but it seems, the solution is not good.

Comment: Setting preferred size is just going to make this worse. Try to remove all calls to setPreferredSize and rely on XxxUI's and LayoutManagers to determine preferred size's.

Comment: how can i use UI ?? is there any example?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. XxxUI's are automatically installed when creating a Swing component. You could implement your own if you wanted but I would rather try to avoid such complex and lengthy process. Remember, get rid of all your calls to `setPreferredSize()` and you should be fine on any platform and any L&F.

Comment: when i get rid off setPreferredSize() like in the above.
then it is fine in ubuntu but in centos text on the button can not be read fully.
For ex: in ubuntu I see text as "My Text".
but in centos it appears like "My Tex..."

Comment: Buttons have insets and margins which you have not taken into account, this is one (of the many) reasons why setXxxSize is not recommended

Answer (score 3):

- `FlowLayout` by default acceptiong `PreferredSize` that came from `JComponents`
- `JButton` by default dont need to re_calculate of `PreferredSize`, let's job for proper `LayoutManager`, `FlowLayout` accepting only `PreferredSize`
- most important is to call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)` (last code lines in constructor) for container (`JFrame`, `JDialog`...)
- every `JComponent` can returns own proper `PreferredSize`, then there no reason override or set this value, this could be different in some cases for empty `JPanel` (pro custom painting) or `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is most likely to happen because of different system fonts being used. You can try to override the native look and feel with a custom one. You may find [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) useful.</strike>

Comment: Incorrect. I just tested his code. Problem is in calling `setPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: Bad for me. Then I'd better remove it.

Comment: @svz and OP can somewhere to put PreferredSize, then all child are shrinked, then (domino effect) this is reason to override PreferredSize for every childs :-)